# ERC721: This contract may be abstract not implement an abstract parents methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly

Tags: solidity

I got the codes below from this link: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md
but its not working ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;
interface ERC721 /* is ERC165 */ {
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _approved, uint256 indexed _tokenId);
    event ApprovalForAll(address indexed _owner, address indexed _operator, bool _approved);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256);
    function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address);
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) external payable;
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;
    function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;
    function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external;
    function getApproved(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address);
    function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) external view returns (bool);
}

interface ERC165 {
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool);
}
```

[image]

Comment: interfaces does not get compiled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005514/difference-between-interface-and-abstract-contract-in-solidity/71008241#71008241

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to deploy an `interface` of ERC721.
If you would like to deploy an ERC721 `contract`, then you should have the contract code as below:

```
contract MyERC721 is ERC721 {
   // your constructor and code here
   ...
}
```

and your MyERC721 contract will succeed the ERC721 interface function.